# oracle connection has been deprecated- framework 4.5

Tags: c#, ado.net, odp.net

I am using ADO.NET for .net framework 4.5 and that saying "oracle connection has been deprecated" but I am able to run the application.

What will happen if I use that for production? Even, one of my application running in the same message on production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen as your running .Net Framework remains the same.
The `deprecated` annotations are here to warn you that in near future, a feature (class, property, method ...) will be removed. Thus, maybe your application won't be able to run anymore on .Net Framework 10.0

Comment: Btw, migrating from ADO.Net to ODP.Net is not too much a big job as quite all the classess and methods kept the same names and signatures. Only their namespace changed from ```System.Data.OracleClient``` to ```Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Can you help me with link CURD operation using ODP.net ? I need atlest insert to table with this?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/CommandExecuteNonQuery.html#GUID-E1E79471-6037-4490-BDE7-ADE252922C83) is an example from the Oracle documentation. It is easy to understand event if one point bothers me : it incites to inject full sql strings though you'd rather have a look to ```OracleParameter``` to define the parameters of your requests